# How to secure session and cookies in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular6

I have a rest API for generating some confidential data and token,
which I'm using in angular 6 client side, currently I am storing it in
session and cookies.

But there it don't have any security for my data.

So my question is, if store token is the local storage for example,
and I have just copied the valid token from another browser, then I
will have a valid token, so there is any security of storing token
like that, and basically the same with cookies, or maybe I missed some
important information?